# Twitter Bootstrap navigation dividers not working properly for google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

My navigation bar isn't displaying the dividers for every subpage element. This is only happening in google chrome,not IE or FF. Here is an image ([click here for larger size of image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmPi5.png)):

[image]

Here is my HTML code:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="/jrknet/www/company" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">
    Company
    <b class="caret">
    </b>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
      <a href="/jrknet/www/company/about-us">
        About us
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/jrknet/www/company/meet-the-team">
        Meet the Team
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/jrknet/www/company/mission-statement">
        Mission Statement
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/jrknet/www/company/development-methodology">
        Development Methodology
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/jrknet/www/company/quality-management">
        Quality Management
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider">
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="/jrknet/www/company/business-continuity">
        Business Continuity
      </a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: try zoom-in, zoom-out the browser window..

Comment: please make your comment a response so i can approve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check zoom-in and zoom-out when such issues arise..

i don't find any problem with the code..

Moreover, if the problem remains, you can try changing your display resolution..

Comment: Same issue: mine was I had set chrome to 90% zoom.  Restored to 100% and it looked fine.